# Stuck up in creation of file in webcontent folder in dynamic web project

Tags: java, file, cron

I want to create a file in my `WebContent` folder in my dynamic `webproject` ,I am calling a class from cron job scheduler and trying to create a file in webcontent folder the creation of file code is in a execute method of that cron job,I tried in many ways but i cant create a file it is saying 
The system cannot find the path that specified

Here's my code

```
File file = new File("files/MatUserInformationService2207q.txt");
                try {
                    file.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block`enter code hereenter code here
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Where is the `.class` file that has the code for creating the file exists? The path to the `File` api should be relative to the project context